# How can a user trigger running GitLab downstream pipeline from upstream pipeline, without permissions to run the downstream pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I need to implement multi-project pipeline trigger in GitLab. Both my upstream & downstream pipelines are GitLab pipelines. Whenever any changes are merged to the master branches of upstream repositories by running upstream pipelines, then the downstream pipeline needs to be re-run on automated basis.

I can use bridge job with triggers, **but the PROBLEM is that users who run the upstream pipelines to update the upstream repositories DON'T have enough permissions to run the downstream pipeline**. In such a case, how can the multi-project pipeline trigger be implemented.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Based on: [Multi-project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html)

> The user that created the upstream pipeline needs to have access
> rights to the downstream project

If a triggered pipeline branch is protected on downstream project, at least "Developer" permission level should be assigned to the member who is triggering the upstream project pipeline

Please see also [Project members permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html), Project members permissions section